# Why is my images not showing under Swiper Slide tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slide

So I am using the SwiperSlide for the first time and after reading the docs and following, I got to the part where i needed it to work and display my images but for some reasons not known to me, my images aren't displaying. Here is my code;

```
      import React from 'react'
      import './residencies.css'
      // core version + navigation, pagination modules:
      import {Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
      // import Swiper and modules styles
      import 'swiper/css';
      import 'swiper/css/navigation';
      import 'swiper/css/pagination';
       import data from '../../utils/slider.json'



         function Residencies() {
         return (
         <div className='r-wrapper'>
         <div className='r-container paddings innerWidth'>
         <div className='r-head flexColStart'>
            <span className='orangeText'>Best Choices</span>
            <span className='primaryText'>Popular Residencies</span>

          </div>

           <Swiper>

            {
                data.map ((card, i) => (
                    <SwiperSlide key={i}>
                        <div className='r-card'>
                            <img src={card.image}alt="" />
                            <span className='secondaryText r-price'>
                                <span>$</span>
                                <span>{card.price}</span>

                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </SwiperSlide>

                )

                )}
            

           </Swiper>
       

            </div>

            </div>
           )
           }

         export default Residencies
```

And here is my data files;

```
       [
       {
       "name": "Aliva Priva Jardin",
       "price": "47,043",
       "detail": "Jakarta Garden City Street, Cakung. Pulo Gadung, Jakarta Timur, DKI Jakarta",
       "image": "/assets/r1.png"
      },
     {
       "name": "Asatti Garden City",
       "price": "66,353",
       "detail": "Pahlawan Street XVII No.215, Cinangka, Sawangan, Depok, Jawa Barat",
       "image": "/assets/r2.png"
     },
     {
      "name": "Citralan Puri Serang",
      "price": "35,853",
      "detail": "Ruko Puri Indah Residence Block A7, Lingkar Street, Ciracas, Serang, Banten",
      "image": "/assets/r3.png"
     },
     {
     "name": "Aliva Priva Jardin",
      "price": "47,043",
      "detail": "Jakarta Garden City Street, Cakung. Pulo Gadung, Jakarta Timur, DKI Jakarta",
      "image": "/assets/r1.png"
     },
     {
      "name": "Asatti Garden City",
      "price": "66,353",
      "detail": "Pahlawan Street XVII No.215, Cinangka, Sawangan, Depok, Jawa Barat",
      "image": "/assets/r2.png"
      },
     {
      "name": "Citralan Puri Serang",
     "price": "35,853",
      "detail": "Ruko Puri Indah Residence Block A7, Lingkar Street, Ciracas, Serang, Banten",
      "image": "/assets/r3.png"
    }
    ]
```

I have tried every possible ways to make sure my image path is correct, I even had to change the image path to traditional way but it wont display still but if i type it outside the SwiperSlide tag It will display. What could be the reasons why it's not showing??

Just the thumbnail is showing, the actual image wont show